# My paper is posted to arXiv; how do I get it endorsed?

Tags: arxiv

I own an article on Arxiv and I am not currently an endorser as it is my first paper. I want this article to be endorsed.

My supervisor is qualified to endorse it but Arxiv is asking for an alpha-numeric endorsement code. Where can we find this code?

Comment: This question is clearly on topic, even though it misunderstands Arxiv.

Comment: @TommiBrander I don't think "How do I use this web form?" questions are on topic.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist The question is not really about how to fill a form, or at the accepted answer is not about that. But maybe you can write another answer to the question that points to the right form.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist This is not about how to fill a form but how to get endorsed. It appears that it helps to clarify the concept of endorsement on ArXiv.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood how the [endorsement system](https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement) works.  Endorsement isn't something that's applied to an *article*, it's applied to an *author*.  It's a one-time process that some people have to go through in order to gain the privilege to submit articles.  Others are granted "automatic endorsement", by virtue of, say, having an academic email address

So if you have already been able to successfully submit a paper, then you don't need endorsement and you never will, and you should just ignore the whole thing.

If you had needed endorsement, you would not have been allowed to submit your first paper, and would instead have been given instructions that included the alphanumeric code.  You would then have given this code to your supervisor, and by logging into their arXiv account, they would have been able to use it to endorse you.  Then you would have been able to go ahead with submitting your paper.

The fact that you are not an *endorser* simply means that if someone else wants to submit their first paper and needs endorsement, you won't be able to be the one to endorse them.  You'll gain this privilege after you have more papers.  But you can't speed it up by being endorsed by someone else.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for this clarification. You are totally right, I thought it was applied to an article and not to an author. This being said, it may be useful in the future that my supervisor endorses me. Do you know where to find the alpha-numeric endorsement code? It is asked by Arxiv when my supervisor tries to endorse me. Thanks

Comment: @A.Ben: I tried to clarify my answer; please reread it.  Endorsement just grants permission to submit papers.  It isn't some sort of reputation-enhancing or networking mechanism.  If you can already post papers, then you already have endorsement, forever, and it is neither necessary nor possible for you to be endorsed by your supervisor.  If you can't, and you don't have automatic endorsement, then you will be presented with a code the first time you try to post a paper.

Comment: Ok I get it now. I wanted to be endorsed in order to be able to publish article without endorsed co-authors but I guess there is no need to take care about that before as long as my papers are accepted. Thanks!

Comment: *"if [...] then you don't need endorsement and you never will"* The way the dcoumentation on the system is written it is clear that arXiv reserves the right to restrict automatic endorsements to, say, certain topics. Not that I have heard of anyone who had positings in one category being required to get an endorsement to post in some other category. I suspect that they've retained the option to give themselves options in hard cases.

Comment: @dmckee I've had it happen when a grad student submitted a paper I was coauthor on to a category none of us had previously posted to (and thus didn't have endorsement privilege for). Though, I don't remember if he found an eligible endorser, or if arxiv moderators just decided to clear it.

Comment: I suspect a misunderstanding. It seems that OP is just a coauthor on a paper that happens to be on arxiv. OP still needs endorsement to be able to publish papers there and they still need to understand what actions should advisor do to endorse OP.

Comment: @Džuris: If that's the case, then my third paragraph explains what to do (change it from the conditional mood to the indicative), or see the last sentence of my first comment.

Comment: @dmckee I've needed endorsement when posting to a new category in the past.

Comment: @Džuris I am the first author of the paper but I have co-authors, including my supervisor. It looks like my co-authors endorsement status was sufficient to get the paper submitted quickly.